# Take screenshot from scrollview

Tags: android, scrollview, screenshot

I have ScrollView. Inside this ScrollView I have HorizontalScrollView. Inside HorizontalScrollView I have RelativeLayout. Here is my layout:

```
<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/scroll"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:scrollbars="none">
   <HorizontalScrollView
     android:id="@+id/hor"
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <RelativeLayout 
        android:id="@+id/lay"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:background="#ffffff" >

    </RelativeLayout >
    </HorizontalScrollView>
</ScrollView>
```

In OnCreate I poputale RelativeLayout  with some controls. Then I try to take screenshoot on all content in ScrollView (this seen on screen ant this not seen on screen). Here is my code:

```
public void takeScreenshot() throws IOException {
        View u = findViewById(R.id.scroll);
        u.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);                                                
        ScrollView z = (ScrollView) findViewById(R.id.scroll);
        z.setEnabled(false);

        int totalHeight = z.getChildAt(0).getHeight();
        int totalWidth = z.getChildAt(0).getWidth();

        int storedHeight = z.getHeight();
        int storedWidth = z.getWidth();

        u.layout(0, 0, totalWidth, totalHeight);    
        u.buildDrawingCache(true);
        Bitmap b = Bitmap.createBitmap(u.getDrawingCache());             
        u.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);
        u.layout(0, 0, storedWidth, storedHeight);

        //Save bitmap
        String extr = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() +   File.separator + "Folder";
        File folderPath = new File(extr);
        folderPath.mkdirs();

        String fileName = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMddhhmm'_report.jpg'").format(new Date());
        File myPath = new File(extr, fileName);

        myPath.createNewFile();

        FileOutputStream fos = null;
        try {
            fos = new FileOutputStream(myPath);
            b.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, fos);
            fos.flush();
            fos.close();
            MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(getContentResolver(), b, "Screen", "screen");
        }catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

I get null in `u.getDrawingCache()` when I try to build bitmap what crash my app. If I comment `u.layout(0, 0, totalWidth, totalHeight);` line it not crashig but my screenshoot is wrong. How can I take screenshoot of all content in ScrollView/what I'm doing wrong here?